# TypeScript sorting an array

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to figure out a very strange issue I ran into with typescript. It was treating an inline Boolean expression as whatever the first value's type was instead of the complete expression.

So if you try something simple like the following:

```
var numericArray:Array<number> = [2,3,4,1,5,8,11];

var sorrtedArray:Array<number> = numericArray.sort((n1,n2)=> n1 > n2);
```

[TryIt](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20numericArray:Array%3Cnumber%3E%20=%20%5B2,3,4,1,5,8,11%5D;%0A%0Avar%20sorrtedArray:Array%3Cnumber%3E%20=%20numericArray.sort%28%28n1,n2%29=%3E%20n1%20%3E%20n2%29;%0A%0A)

You will get an error on your sort method saying the parameters do not match any signature of the call target, because your result is numeric and not Boolean. I guess I'm missing something though cause I'm pretty sure n1>n2 is a Boolean statement.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

The error is completely correct.

As it's trying to tell you, `.sort()` takes a function that returns number, not boolean.

You need to return negative if the first item is smaller; positive if it it's larger, or zero if they're equal.

Answer (score 387):

## Numbers

When sorting numbers, you can use the compact comparison:

```
var numericArray: number[] = [2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 8, 11];

var sortedArray: number[] = numericArray.sort((n1,n2) => n1 - n2);
```

i.e. `-` rather than `<`.

## Other Types

If you are comparing anything else, you'll need to convert the comparison into a number.

```
var stringArray: string[] = ['AB', 'Z', 'A', 'AC'];

var sortedArray: string[] = stringArray.sort((n1,n2) => {
    if (n1 > n2) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (n1 < n2) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

## Objects

For objects, you can sort based on a property, bear in mind the above information about being able to short-hand number types. The below example works irrespective of the type.

```
var objectArray: { age: number; }[] = [{ age: 10}, { age: 1 }, {age: 5}];

var sortedArray: { age: number; }[] = objectArray.sort((n1,n2) => {
    if (n1.age > n2.age) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (n1.age < n2.age) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Could some one explain why, for the less-than test, 'Roy@my.net' returns true for less than 'bob@my.net'?  e.g.: let myTest = ('Roy@my.net' < 'bob@my.net'); // returns true for me... :(

Comment: in the second case you can use localeCompare() to compare strings in the current locale, which returns a number

Comment: Please explain me, How `(n1,n2)=>n1-n2` expression will execute or work..??

Comment: @RahulChaudhari in the number example, it's a function that takes the numbers `n1` and `n2`, within the function it returns `n1-n2`, which will either be a positive number, zero, or a negative number. This tells the sort operation whether the items need to be switched or not, thus enabling sorting.

Comment: its can be possible filter with different proprty

Comment: @arvind yes - example added to help with that.

Comment: A terser solution is to use lambda and not care about equal strings as they are sorted already: `objectArray.sort((n1,n2=>{n1.age>=n2.age?1:-1});`

Answer (score 29):

Great answer Sohnee.
Would like to add that if you have an array of objects and you wish to sort by key then its almost the same, this is an example of one that can sort by both date(number) or title(string):

```
    if (sortBy === 'date') {
        return n1.date - n2.date
    } else {
        if (n1.title > n2.title) {
           return 1;
        }
        if (n1.title < n2.title) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Could also make the values inside as variables n1[field] vs n2[field] if its more dynamic, just keep the diff between strings and numbers.

Comment: Commenting on answers should be done using the comments function.

Comment: @Nicktar It's probably posted as an answer for the formatting. But it doesn't do any harm anyway

Answer (score 14):

```
let numericArray: number[] = [2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 8, 11];

let sortFn = (n1 , n2) => number { return n1 - n2; }

const sortedArray: number[] = numericArray.sort(sortFn);
```

Sort by some field:

```
let arr:{key:number}[] = [{key : 2}, {key : 3}, {key : 4}, {key : 1}, {key : 5}, {key : 8}, {key : 11}];

let sortFn2 = (obj1 , obj2) => {key:number} { return obj1.key - obj2.key; }

const sortedArray2:{key:number}[] = arr.sort(sortFn2);
```

Comment: n1 - n2 is negative when n1 < n2, positive when n1 > n2 and 0 when n1 == n2

Comment: Thanks! I changed it  for this:  myArray.sort((a, b): number => { return a.NumberProp - b.NumberProp; });

Comment: `{key:number}` in sorting function is not working in my typescript file... removed it... now working, where I have `key:Date` data type

Answer (score 12):

#### Sort Mixed Array (alphabets and numbers)

```js
function naturalCompare(a, b) {
   var ax = [], bx = [];

   a.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function (_, $1, $2) { ax.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });
   b.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function (_, $1, $2) { bx.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });

   while (ax.length && bx.length) {
     var an = ax.shift();
     var bn = bx.shift();
     var nn = (an[0] - bn[0]) || an[1].localeCompare(bn[1]);
     if (nn) return nn;
   }

   return ax.length - bx.length;
}

let builds = [ 
    { id: 1, name: 'Build 91'}, 
    { id: 2, name: 'Build 32' }, 
    { id: 3, name: 'Build 13' }, 
    { id: 4, name: 'Build 24' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Build 5' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Build 56' }
]

let sortedBuilds = builds.sort((n1, n2) => {
  return naturalCompare(n1.name, n2.name)
})

console.log('Sorted by name property')
console.log(sortedBuilds)
```

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way seems to be subtracting the second number from the first:

```
var numericArray:Array<number> = [2,3,4,1,5,8,11];

var sortedArray:Array<number> = numericArray.sort((n1,n2) => n1 - n2);
```

https://alligator.io/js/array-sort-numbers/

Answer (score 1):

i use this

```
type SortArrayType = <T>(arr: T[]) => T[];

const sortArray: SortArrayType = (arr) => {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => {
    const strA = JSON.stringify(a);
    const strB = JSON.stringify(b);
    if (strA < strB) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (strA > strB) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For strings I do this,

```
let unSortedArray = ['d', 'b', 'c', 'a'];
let sortedArray = unSortedArray.sort((x, y) => x > y ? 1 : x < y ? -1 : 0)
```

which easily can be extended to more complex types e.g. dictionaries. In that case, instead of `x, y` use `x.whicheverKey, y.whicheverKey` e.g.

```
unSortedObjectArray.sort((x, y) => x.whicheverKey > y.whicheverKey ? 1 : x.whicheverKey < y.whicheverKey ? -1 : 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this one today while trying to recreate `_.sortBy` in TypeScript, and thought I would leave it for anyone in need.

```
// ** Credits for getKeyValue at the bottom **
export const getKeyValue = <T extends {}, U extends keyof T>(key: U) => (obj: T) => obj[key] 

export const sortBy = <T extends {}>(index: string, list: T[]): T[] => {
    return list.sort((a, b): number => {
        const _a = getKeyValue<keyof T, T>(index)(a)
        const _b = getKeyValue<keyof T, T>(index)(b)
        if (_a < _b) return -1
        if (_a > _b) return 1
        return 0
    })
}
```

#### Usage:

It expects an array of generic type T, hence the cast for `<T extends {}>`, as well as typing the parameter and function return type with `T[]`

```
const x = [{ label: 'anything' }, { label: 'goes'}]
const sorted = sortBy('label', x)
```

** `getByKey` fn found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b#answer-60274490)