# Angular 4 data-table sorting from nested json

Tags: javascript, json, angular, datatable, nested

Require help on Angular data-table with nested data.

I want to sort the data in table.

I am using data table from - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable

Data table works fine for single array type data. (used for many angular applications)

**ISSUE:** i have nested json (in reality, i have complex json, making here simple)

Thanks for looking into this.

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

**JSON**

```
records = [
  [
    {
      "name": "Subject Name",
      "type": "text",
      "id": "subjectName",
      "value": "DavidJ",
      "firstName": "David",
      "lastName": "John"
    },
    {
      "name": "QC Name",
      "type": "hidden",
      "id": "qcName",
      "value": "JosephT",
      "firstName": "Joseph",
      "lastName": "Tom"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Subject Name",
      "type": "text",
      "id": "subjectName",
      "value": "TigerC",
      "firstName": "Tiger",
      "lastName": "Chan"
    },
    {
      "name": "QC Name",
      "type": "hidden",
      "id": "qcName",
      "value": "ThomasR",
      "firstName": "Thomas",
      "lastName": "Richard"
    }
  ]
]
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover" [mfData]="this.records | dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage" [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>
         <mfDefaultSorter by="subjectName">subject Name</mfDefaultSorter>
      </th>
      <th>
         <mfDefaultSorter by="qcPerson">QC Person</mfDefaultSorter>
      </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody *ngIf="!isLoading">
   <tr class="border" *ngFor="let sample of mf.data; let i='index'">
      <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of sample">
         <td *ngIf="item.id ==='subjectName'">
            {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
         </td>
         <td *ngIf="item.id ==='qcPerson'">
            {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
         </td>
      </ng-container>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

TYpescript file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OrderBy } from '../all_services/OrderByPipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-userdashboard',
    templateUrl: './userdashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../header-footer/css/external.style.css']
})

export class UserdashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}


    /** Sorting functions */
    public data;
    public filterQuery = "";
    public rowsOnPage = 10;
    public sortBy = "subjectName";
    public sortOrder = "asc";

    public toInt(num: string) {
        return +num;
    }
}
```

**Datafilterpipe.ts**

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
    name: "dataFilter"
})
export class DataFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: any[], query: string): any {
        if (query) {
            return _.filter(array, row=>row.name.indexOf(query) > -1);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear - what you are you trying to do that you need help with?

Comment: @GabrielDoty , apologies if i am not clear. i want to sort the data in table.

Comment: why are you using array inside array, can't you simply put all objects inside one array, so that sorting of array of objects will be much easier

Comment: What about flattening the JSON before populating the table? 
https://angular-yfpnk4.stackblitz.io

Comment: @Prasanna Sasne, i am afraid i am unable to do that. i am using same json in many other components. i have compex nested json, here i am displaying very simple json

Comment: @Sid, your example is what i expected. :) could you please give me a sample.

Comment: Sure, [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfpnk4) is the StackBlitz I created from your records. You don't have change your JSON; you can flatten it using [lodash](https://lodash.com) for displaying/sort/paginating using AngularMaterial Table. You can use `flatten` or `flattenDeep` based on how complex your JSON is.

Comment: Why not you map or build other JSON form the existing JSON and all of them before you input in the data table.

Comment: @Sid, your answer is very near to what i expect. i have few queries. 1. how to hide hidden fields(i tried, table is not working). 2. you are checking 'type' (matColumnDef="type") i have multiple set of arrays which has similar properties (eg: checkboxes). 3. Can you please write as a anaswer so that i can make it usable and possibly award the bounty. please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @ Abel Valdez, i tried. but i felt that is not a good thing to do. what if data (json) changes tomorrow? i am looking for a dynamic solution. let me know if you have any other ideas, possibly map or build other json. if you think there, otherwise please make an answer. that would be very helpful. thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Do you want to sort 'qcName' and 'subjectName' when i click on it's corresponding column?  or all objects you want to display in separate row? as 'Sid' has done in his example.?

Comment: @Prasanna Sasne, i want to sort all objects, for e.g: how typical sorting works in data table. yes exactly like 'Sid'

Comment: I've modified my code, check it once.Hope this may be useful to you

Comment: Guys, now i have a sorting working but not proper one. using 'Krishna' 's answer any suggestions would be helpful for me. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 6):

I had face the same issue. I had used [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp) table sort logic once the table is rendered in DOM.

It works really smooth with angular2-datatable as I am using the same datatable in my project. Its usage is very straight, stillif you face any issue please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Below will be implementation
Function in your TS file.

```
  columnSorter(n) {
    let table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchCount = 0;
    switching = true;
    this.clickSort = !this.clickSort
    dir = "asc";
    table = document.querySelector('.smallTable');
    while (switching) {
      switching = false;
      rows = table.rows;
      for (i = 0; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
        shouldSwitch = false;
        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
        if (dir == 'asc') {
          if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
            shouldSwitch = true;
            break;
          }
        } else if (dir == 'desc') {
          if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
            shouldSwitch = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (shouldSwitch) {
        rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
        switching = true;
        switchCount++;
      } else {
        if (switchCount == 0 && dir == 'asc') {
          dir = 'desc';
          switching = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In you HTML table on th just add below, where 0 is column no.

```
(click)="columnSorter(0)
```

Comment: It really doesn't fulfill my requirement. thanks for the idea. i really appreciate it.

Comment: If you dont mind can you tell me what is your requirement?

Comment: i want to sort the table headers by clicking up and down arrow arrow.
I have 4 tables, i dont want users to have one more button to sort.

Comment: You dont require seperate button, call that function on column click.. Check my edited answer

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa If my answer is solving your purpose then then please mark it as answer

Comment: I am getting error on this 'this.clickSort = !this.clickSort' and also i need sorting icons. can you please help me on this.

Comment: Define as clickSort:boolean = false; at begaining of the component.

Comment: <span [ngClass] ="clickSort ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom'"></span> Just add this code.. I have used glyphicon, You can use any other icon like material and toggle them based on clickSort

Comment: Cool, it is working is good so far!. :)  One minor issue, i want use this code to multiple tables, but its not working. any suggestions or workaround. Thanks again for looking into this issue.

Comment: Create table as a component and keep all table related core functionalities in that component and just pass data to table using @Input property thats it.. Hope that helps.. Please mark answer as accepted.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: sorting is not perfect. i have date column, which is not sorted properly. can you please help me here

Answer (score 5):

Using this library you have to use these input variables to sort table once:

```
mfSortBy: any - sort by parameter
mfSortOrder: string - sort order parameter, "asc" or "desc"
```

Also you can add this tag to you th to allow user to sort it by click:

```
<mfDefaultSorter by="name">Name</mfDefaultSorter>
```

To create custom sort for the table you just need to sort yours json.
In your case you should operate with what you assign to mf.data.

You can create custom derective where you will create sorter for a table and then sort data by click.

e.g.

```
import {
Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewChecked,
Input, Output, Renderer, EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
   selector: '[sorter], [defaultSorter]'
})
export class TableSorterDerective implements AfterViewChecked {
  @Input()
  sorter: {order:string, property:string};
  @Output()
  sorted = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    let element: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement;
    if(this.sorter){
      this.addSorter(element);
    }
  }

  addSorter(column: HTMLElement){
    if(!column.classList.contains("custom_sorter")){
      column.addEventListener('click', () => this.sendSort(column), false)
      column.classList.add("custom_sorter");
    }
  }

  sendSort(element:HTMLElement){
    let columns: HTMLElement[] = 
Array.prototype.slice.call(element.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('th'), 0);
    columns.forEach(element => {
      if(!element.classList.contains(this.sorter.property)){
        let icon = element.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
        if(icon) icon.remove();
      }
    });

    let icon:HTMLElement = element.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
    if(!icon) icon = this.renderer.createElement(element, 'span');
    icon.classList.remove("glyphicon-triangle-bottom")
    icon.classList.remove("glyphicon-triangle-top")
    icon.classList.remove("glyphicon")

    if(this.sorter.order == "asc"){
      this.sorter = {order:"desc", property:this.sorter.property}
      icon.classList.add("glyphicon")
      icon.classList.add("glyphicon-triangle-top")
    }else if(this.sorter.order == "desc"){
      this.sorter = {order:"asc", property:this.sorter.property}
      icon.classList.add("glyphicon")
      icon.classList.add("glyphicon-triangle-bottom")
    }
    this.sorted.emit(this.sorter)
  }
}
```

and then you just need to sort data on emit:

```
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [sorter]="col.sorting ? {order:'desc', property:col.property} : undefined" (sorted)="transformationsService.sort(filteredData, $event)"</th>
```

To sort data just use sort function e.g. :

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
        return 0 - (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1)
      }
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687907/typescript-sorting-an-array) if you need help with sort function.

Comment: thank you let me check. i am not looking for custom sort, but i will try that as well.

Comment: you should know that this table allows you to sort only by first layer properties, so if you want to use not customized sorter you need to simplify input data to objects like {subjectName:string; qcPerson:string}  and then you can use <mfDefaultSorter by="subjectName">Name</mfDefaultSorter>

Answer (score 5):

To sort the data you could always use Lodash's very powerful `_.sortBy`:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

const nestedData = [
    { a: { b: 2} },
    { a: { b: 1} },
    { a: { b: 3} } 
];

// Outputs ​​​​​[ { a: { b: 1 } }, { a: { b: 2 } }, { a: { b: 3 } } ]​​​​​
_.sortBy(nestedData, item =>  _.get(item, ['a', 'b']));
```

It even supports sorting by multiple fields:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

const nestedData = [
    { a: { b: 2 }, c: 'a' },
    { a: { b: 1 }, c: 'b' },
    { a: { b: 1 }, c: 'd'} 
];

// Output: 
​​​​​// [ { a: { b: 1 }, c: 'b' },​​​​​
​​​​​//   { a: { b: 1 }, c: 'd' },​​​​​
​​​​​//   { a: { b: 2 }, c: 'a' } ]​​​​​
_.sortBy(nestedData, [item =>  _.get(item, ['a', 'b']), item => _.get(item, 'c')]);
```

As far as adding this to your current table -- there are a lot of ways you can achieve that. It might be easier to pre-sort your data before you pass it the table. If the user clicks a column header -- simply run the data through the appropriate `_.sortBy` and dump it back into the table?

Comment: can you please give me fiddle or plunker with json, if possible please

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using dataTable you can implement custom pipe, which will sort the data, without changing original object. Some how you want to sort the data when you clicked on columns. Here is simple code, hope this works for you.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({
  name: "orderby",
  pure: false
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: Array<any>, args?: any) {
    let newDataArray:any = [];      
        if (array.length > 0 && args.value != undefined) {
        for (let item of array) {
            for (let subItem of item) {
                newDataArray.push(subItem);
            }
        }
        newDataArray.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
                    if ((a.firstName).toLowerCase() < (b.firstName).toLowerCase()) {
                        return -1 * args.direction;
                    } else if ((a.firstName).toLowerCase() > (b.firstName).toLowerCase()) {
                        return 1 * args.direction;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
        array = Array.from(newDataArray);  
        }
       return array;
     }
    }
```

To call this pipe from your component use code as below, define these variables

```
isDesc: boolean = false;
direction: number = 1;
filterData = [];
```

and

```
  orderByMe(toBeSorted: string){
     this.isDesc = !this.isDesc;
     this.direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;
     this.filterData = Array.from(new OrderByPipe().transform( this.records, { 
     value: toBeSorted, direction: this.direction } ));
   } 

  ngOnInit(){
    this.orderByMe('subjectName');
  }
```

In Html template you can use

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th (click)="orderByMe('subjectName')">subjectName</th>
  <th (click)="orderByMe('qcName')">qcPerson</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let record of filterData; let currentIndex = index;">
  <td>{{ currentIndex + 1}}</td>
  <td>{{ record.firstName }}</td>
  <td>{{ record.lastName }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```