# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index

Tags: typescript

Trying out TypeScript for a React project and I'm stuck on this error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ train_1: boolean; train_2: boolean; train_3: boolean; train_4: boolean; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ train_1: boolean; train_2: boolean; train_3: boolean; train_4: boolean; }'
```

Which appears when I try to filter the array in my component

```
.filter(({ name }) => plotOptions[name]);
```

So far I looked at the article "Indexing objects in TypeScript" (https://dev.to/kingdaro/indexing-objects-in-typescript-1cgi) since it had a similar error, but I tried to add the index signature to type `plotTypes` and I still get the same error.

My component code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import createPlotlyComponent from "react-plotly.js/factory";
import Plotly from "plotly.js-basic-dist";
const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly);

interface IProps {
  data: any;
}

interface IState {
  [key: string]: plotTypes;
  plotOptions: plotTypes;
}

type plotTypes = {
  [key: string]: boolean;
  train_1: boolean;
  train_2: boolean;
  train_3: boolean;
  train_4: boolean;
};

interface trainInfo {
  name: string;
  x: Array<number>;
  y: Array<number>;
  type: string;
  mode: string;
}

class FiltrationPlots extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  readonly state = {
    plotOptions: {
      train_1: true,
      train_2: true,
      train_3: true,
      train_4: true
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const { plotOptions } = this.state;

    if (data.filtrationData) {
      const plotData: Array<trainInfo> = [
        {
          name: "train_1",
          x: data.filtrationData.map((i: any) => i["1-CumVol"]),
          y: data.filtrationData.map((i: any) => i["1-PressureA"]),
          type: "scatter",
          mode: "lines"
        },
        {
          name: "train_2",
          x: data.filtrationData.map((i: any) => i["2-CumVol"]),
          y: data.filtrationData.map((i: any) => i["2-PressureA"]),
          type: "scatter",
          mode: "lines"
        },
        {
          name: "train_3",
          x: data.filtrationData.map((i: any) => i["3-CumVol"]),
          y: data.filtrationData.map((i: any) => i["3-PressureA"]),
          type: "scatter",
          mode: "lines"
        },
        {
          name: "train_4",
          x: data.filtrationData.map((i: any) => i["4-CumVol"]),
          y: data.filtrationData.map((i: any) => i["4-PressureA"]),
          type: "scatter",
          mode: "lines"
        }
      ].filter(({ name }) => plotOptions[name]);
      return (
        <Plot
          data={plotData}
          layout={{ width: 1000, height: 1000, title: "A Fancy Plot" }}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return <h1>No Data Loaded</h1>;
    }
  }
}

export default FiltrationPlots;
```

Answer (score 396, accepted):

This happens because you try to access `plotOptions` property using string `name`. TypeScript understands that `name` may have any value, not only property name from `plotOptions`. So TypeScript requires to add index signature to `plotOptions`, so it knows that you can use any property name in `plotOptions`. But I suggest to change type of `name`, so it can only be one of `plotOptions` properties.

```
interface trainInfo {
    name: keyof typeof plotOptions;
    x: Array<number>;
    y: Array<number>;
    type: string;
    mode: string;
}
```

Now you'll be able to use only property names that exist in `plotOptions`.

You also have to slightly change your code.

First assign array to some temp variable, so TS knows array type:

```
const plotDataTemp: Array<trainInfo> = [
    {
      name: "train_1",
      x: data.filtrationData.map((i: any) => i["1-CumVol"]),
      y: data.filtrationData.map((i: any) => i["1-PressureA"]),
      type: "scatter",
      mode: "lines"
    },
    // ...
}
```

Then filter:

```
const plotData = plotDataTemp.filter(({ name }) => plotOptions[name]);
```

If you're getting data from API and have no way to type check props at compile time the only way is to add index signature to your `plotOptions`:

```
type tplotOptions = {
    [key: string]: boolean
}

const plotOptions: tplotOptions = {
    train_1: true,
    train_2: true,
    train_3: true,
    train_4: true
}
```

Comment: ```{[key: string]: boolean}```

this helped a lot, very intiutive

Comment: You can also skip the whole type/interface and declare `const plotOptions:{[key:string]:boolean} = {....}`

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77540162/unable-to-fetch-a-field-from-a-table-in-react/77540481?noredirect=1#comment136699940_77540481

Answer (score 1064):

For anyone who stumbles upon this in the future:

If you're getting the TypeScript error

> '...expression of type string cannot be used to index...'

then simply specify that the 'expression of type string' is a **key of** the **type of**  that object. For example,

```
const someObj:ObjectType = data;
const field = 'username';

// This gives an error
const temp = someObj[field];

// Solution 1: When the type of the object is known
const temp = someObj[field as keyof ObjectType]

// Solution 2: When the type of the object is not known
const temp = someObj[field as keyof typeof someObj]
```

Comment: this show "Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never" error

Comment: @Franklin'jGil'z Can you share a snippet? If you have a type specified implicitly or explicitly, you shouldn't get that error.

Comment: @VikramDeshmukh thanks for the edit, but I deleted my comment. There was a large amount of edge cases I wasn't factoring in. See this huge discussion about it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732 As far as I can digest, its not yet a solved problem

Comment: If you index an object T with a key that is not in this object, the resulting value is undefined. The type you want is T[K] | undefined, not just T[K].

Comment: Or like `const myObject: Record<string, any> = {}`

Comment: Is there a less verbose solution? because this really hurt readability

Comment: Is there a specific TS setting specific to this particular aspect of the "no implicit any" setting? Because throwing a compiler error in JavaScript from indexing using a string is IMO going too far (though I understand many think this is ok).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this workaround! I just wish there was a way to TS to infer the types of the keys of an interface with builtin Object/Array methods. Considering an object with static keys defined in its corresponding interface, it seems like TS should be able to infer them no problem, but I suppose not today.

Answer (score 141):

When using `Object.keys`, the following works:

```
Object.keys(this)
    .forEach(key => {
      console.log(this[key as keyof MyClass]);
    });
```

Comment: Excellent! Why does this solve the issue?

Comment: @Andru this solves the issue because TS recognizes that the `key` is something that `this` actually has. In fact, we can even get rid of the class name and use `this` instead like `this[key as keyof this]`!

Comment: @ChristosLytras I see. A pity TypeScript has to be told this by a type cast. ..What else could `key` actually be when it's a loop over the elements of `Object.keys`? - In a future TypeScript version such a type cast might not be necessary, I guess.

Answer (score 101):

I use this:

```
interface IObjectKeys {
  [key: string]: string | number;
}

interface IDevice extends IObjectKeys {
  id: number;
  room_id: number;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  description: string;
}
```

NOTE: "[key: string]" what is it? An object in JavaScript is primarily just a collection of properties made up of key-value pairs. Moreover, the key can only be a **string** (even for array elements), but the value can be any data type.

If you use the optional property in your object:

```
interface IDevice extends IObjectKeys {
  id: number;
  room_id?: number;
  name?: string;
  type?: string;
  description?: string;
}
```

... you should add 'undefined' value into the IObjectKeys interface:

```
interface IObjectKeys {
  [key: string]: string | number | undefined;
}
```

Comment: If i want to make some of the property optional? 
for example `room_id?:number;`

Comment: You can do this. I think it has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: Nope `?optional` that means maybe `undefined` so should I add it like this `[key: string]: string | number | undefined`.
 that solves the issue `Property 'room_id' of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'string | number'.` :)

Comment: Oh, I see :). You are right! :) Thank you!

Comment: @GennadyMagomaev Hello, I had the same problem and your answer helped me out a lot! I dont fully understand what this means though : "[key: string]: string | number".  Does it mean that the key of the object can be a string and after the " :" does it mean it can also be a string or number or ? I got confused... Could you be kind enough to explain it to me please ?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your question! I added a new description. Look, an object in JavaScript is primarily just a collection of properties made up of key-value pairs. Moreover, the key can only be a string (even for array elements), but the value can be any data type. I had answered your question?

Comment: Best, cleanest, and most flexible solution.

Comment: You can also just extend Record<string, any>, Replace any with options if you want.

Comment: Thanks, in my case, only add an index in my type [key: string] was enough.

Answer (score 85):

I fixed this issue by using `keyof`

```
messageMap = {
 "Hi": "Hello",
 "Who are you": "My name is Test Sat Bot",
 "What is your role": "Just guide for the user",
}
```

this ❌

```
let answer = this.messageMap[question];
```

replace with ✔️

```
let answer = this.messageMap[question as keyof typeof this.messageMap];
```

Here `question` is type of `string`

```
getBotMessage(question: string){    
  let answer = this.messageMap[question as keyof typeof this.messageMap];
}
```

Comment: another reason why TS solves less problems than it creates. You go from 39 chars of valid JS code that works 100% of the time to 71 chars of TS that just compiled down to the original 39 chars. so dumb.

Comment: Yes I had to replace it like 300x in my code:
Before: ```strings.names[nameId]```
After: ```strings.names[nameId.toString() as keyof typeof strings.names])```

Answer (score 84):

```
// bad
const _getKeyValue = (key: string) => (obj: object) => obj[key];

// better
const _getKeyValue_ = (key: string) => (obj: Record<string, any>) => obj[key];

// best
const getKeyValue = <T extends object, U extends keyof T>(key: U) => (obj: T) =>
  obj[key];
```

Bad - the reason for the error is the `object` type is just an empty object by default. Therefore it isn't possible to use a `string` type to index `{}`.

Better - the reason the error disappears is because now we are telling the compiler the `obj` argument will be a collection of string/value (`string/any`) pairs. However, we are using the `any` type, so we can do better.

Best - `T` extends empty object. `U` extends the keys of `T`. Therefore `U` will always exist on `T`, therefore it can be used as a look up value.

**Here is a full example:**

I have switched the order of the generics (`U extends keyof T` now comes before `T extends object`) to highlight that order of generics is not important and you should select an order that makes the most sense for your function.

```js
const getKeyValue = <U extends keyof T, T extends object>(key: U) => (obj: T) =>
  obj[key];

interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const user: User = {
  name: "John Smith",
  age: 20
};

const getUserName = getKeyValue<keyof User, User>("name")(user);

// => 'John Smith'
```

### Alternative Syntax

```js
const getKeyValue = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K] => obj[key];
```

Comment: I wrote a tiny [npm package](https://github.com/alexandermckay/get-key-value) with this function to make this task easier for those that are new to Typescript.

Comment: The package is approximately 38 bytes once packaged and minified.

Answer (score 30):

I have made a simulation of the problem. looks like the issue is how we should
**Access Object Properties Dynamically Using Bracket Notation in Typescript**

```
interface IUserProps {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

export default class User {
  constructor(private data: IUserProps) {}

  get(propName: string): string | number {
    return this.data[propName as keyof IUserProps];
  }
}
```

I found a blog that might be helpful to understand this better.

here is a link
https://www.nadershamma.dev/blog/2019/how-to-access-object-properties-dynamically-using-bracket-notation-in-typescript/

Comment: Sorry for that @double-beep, I have UPDATED my post. It was actually my first post to answer a question here.

Comment: This response is simple and the link explains perfectly the problem and the solution

Answer (score 15):

When we do something like this obj[key] Typescript can't know for sure if that key exists in that object. What I did:

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(item => {
    formData.append(item[0], item[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 11):

This might help someone
First the empty object need to be with the type `Record<string, any>` so it will accept key as `string` and value as `any`

```
const sortFields: Record<string, any> = {};
const keyName = `field`;

sortFields[keyName] = 'asc';
```

So here when we log `sortFields`

```
 console.log("sortFields==== ", sortFields); // sortFields==== {field: 'asc'}
```

Or if we want to add more than one element in the object we can do it like this

```
sortFields.email = "asc"; // Or sortFields["email"] = "asc"; but its better written in dot notation.
sortFields.name = "desc";
sortFields.phone = "desc";
```

So now when we log `sortFields`

```
 console.log("sortFields==== ", sortFields); // sortFields==== {field: 'asc', email: 'asc', name: 'desc', phone: 'desc'}
```

Answer (score 8):

With out `typescript` error

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(newCategory).forEach((k,i)=>{  
        var d =Object.values(newCategory)[i];
        formData.append(k,d) 
    })
```

Comment: works fine, but i suggest to use forEach instead of map, cause a map usually returns something.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Alex Mckay I had a resolve for dynamic setting a props:

```
  for(let prop in filter)
      (state.filter as Record<string, any>)[prop] = filter[prop];
```

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me with `keyof` and `as` operators:

```
const keys: [keyof ITrainInfo] = Object.keys(this.trainInfo) as [
    keyof ITrainInfo,
]
keys.forEach((property) => {
    // console.log(tmpUser[property])
    if (this.trainInfo === undefined) return
    if (this.trainInfo[property] !== undefined) {
        // your code here
        /*const trainsToSet = trains.find((field) => field.name === property)
        if (trainsToSet != undefined)
            trainsToSet.value = this.trainInfo[property]?.toString()
        */
    }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

as a last resort, you can mute this error by setting `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true` in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I made some small changes to Alex McKay's function/usage that I think make it a little easier to follow why it works and also adheres to the [no-use-before-define](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define) rule.

First, define this function to use:

```
const getKeyValue = function<T extends object, U extends keyof T> (obj: T, key: U) { return obj[key] }
```

In the way I've written it, the generic for the function lists the object first, then the property on the object second (these can occur in any order, but if you specify `U extends key of T` before `T extends object` you break the `no-use-before-define` rule, and also it just makes sense to have the object first and its' property second. Finally, I've used the more common function syntax instead of the arrow operators (`=>`).

Anyways, with those modifications you can just use it like this:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const user: User = {
  name: "John Smith",
  age: 20
};

getKeyValue(user, "name")
```

Which, again, I find to be a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript needs to be sure those values exist in trainInfo, else it reads all as string

instead of doing this

```
interface trainInfo {
  name: string;
  x: Array<number>;
  y: Array<number>;
  type: string;
  mode: string;
}
```

do this

```
interface trainInfo {
  name: "train_1" | "train_2" | "train_3"| "train_4";
  x: Array<number>;
  y: Array<number>;
  type: string;
  mode: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In situation of nested object, if want `for in` in `for in` , here is a working example without error warning:

```
export const X = {
  aa: {
    a: '1',
    b: '2',
  },
  bb: {
    a: '3',
    b: '4',
  },
} as const

export const f1 = () => {
  let k1: keyof typeof X
  for (k1 in X) {
    console.log(k1)

    let k2: keyof (typeof X)[keyof typeof X]
    for (k2 in X[k1]) {
      console.log(X[k1][k2])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For use with a `reduce` function. Make sure you properly type the accumulator.

Example:

```js
const getNestedLevels = (
  subjects: TutorSubject[] | TutorActivity[] | undefined,
) => {
  if (subjects === undefined) {
    return {};
  }
  return subjects.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => {
      let subject;
      let level;

      if (curr.specialization) {
        subject = curr.specialization.name;
      }

      if (curr.specializationLevel) {
        level = curr.specializationLevel.name;
      }

      if (subject && level) {
        acc[subject] = [...(subject in acc ? acc[subject] : []), level];
      }

      return acc;
    },
    {} as { [key: string]: string[] }, //  type this acc
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a answer to the original question, but a generic work around to this problem.

Original problem:
`person[cr.field]` causes this error

---

I'm doing a generic *advanced search* form where user can select a field, comparator and the desired value. When trying to read the value from the object based on the key, I get this error (altought the `field` value is type of string and I think it should be just fine)

So what I do is I extract the [key, value] like this

```
const x: [string, any] = Object.entries(person).find(([key, _]) => key === cr.field);
```

For example if my criterion (`cr`) is `{ field: 'name', value: 'John' }` and field `name` actually exists in a person obj., it should return the field name and the value as tuple (x is `[string, any]` or undef). If not found, undefined.

Answer (score 0):

public getUserName(): string {

```
const accessToken = this.getAccessToken();
const claims:any = this.getUserClaims();
console.log('access token ',accessToken);
this.getUserInfo();
return claims['sub'].split('@')[0];
```

}

//give any type to the variable

Answer (score 0):

You can also utilize `switch` with fall-through statements:

```
switch (prop) {
    case 'propOne':
    case 'propTwo':
    case 'propThree':
        return someObj[prop];
    default:
        return false;
}
```

As long as those props exist on `someObj`, you will not get a TypeScript error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today as well, tried what mentioned above to use `keyof`, but it thorws another error saying `"Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never".`

Did some research and turns out it's because ts thinks that the key I have could be any string, and such key string may not exist in my object

take this for example

```
interface MyObj {
    [abc as string]: string;
    [xyz as string]: boolean;
}
const flag: boolean = true;
const newObj: MyObj = cloneDeep(myObj);
const myKey: string = someKeyFromSomewhereXYZ; // for my situation my key was passed in as a child of an object prop from parent component
newObj[myKey as keyof MyObj] = !flag; // this is where my error pops, and doing keyof won't fix the issue.
```

so for me to fix the issue, what I did was to add the specific key to `myKey`, make it look like this

```
const myKey: 'xyz' = someKeyFromSomewhereXYZ
```

it seems like ts thinks that `myKey` could be any sting, hence doing `newObj[myKey]` could be `undefined`, which leads to 'never' in ts I guess.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's a little too late, but all it's needed is to add a little type conversion, I wrote a static function that safely-returns the array of keys with the correct typing. All you need is to define the type and pass the object as a parameter:

```
export class ObjectUtil {
  public static getObjectKeys<T>(obj: Object) {
    if (!obj) {
      return [];
    }

    return Object.keys(obj).map((key: string) => key as keyof T);
  }
}
```

Below is a simple example:

```
ObjectUtil.getObjectKeys<Address>(address).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(address[key]);
});
```

Answer (score -28):

This is what it worked for me. The `tsconfig.json` has an option `noImplicitAny` that it was set to `true`, I just simply set it to `false` and now I can access properties in objects using strings.

Comment: This will remove strict, then there is no point in using typescript if we keep removing these restrictions.

Comment: I don't agree @JosephBriggs. Typescript brings to the table so many other benefits. Type check is one of them. Is nice that you can opt-in or out depending on the requirements of your project.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, it just ignores it.

Comment: @Zeke I understand mate :) I was in a rush writing. What I meant is that if we keep solving the issues by just telling it to ignore then there is no point of it in the first place. but then again all depends on the project, and the decisions per project.

Comment: I prefer this... even strong type language like c# have "var". 
Refering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62377614/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b ...
A bit over engineered to put all sort of bumping code to access a simple property.

Comment: `var` in C# is not like `any` in Typescript. `var` will not work in a strongly typed language like `C#` if the type cannot be inferred, whereas `any` allows a variable to take on any type *at any time* - an `any` variable can be reassigned to a value of a completely different type. This is not possible in `C#`.

Comment: Even with `noImplicitAny`, you can still use `any`. You just can't do it *accidentally*, and the no-accidents guarantee one of the largest benefits of strong type checking.

Comment: You are telling the TypeScript that doesn't be itself