# React TypeScript how to iterate through an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This is specific for React.

I have an object like this:

```js
interface Profile {
    name: string;
    title: string;
}

const NewPerson: Profile = {
    name: "John Smith",
    title: "Software Engineer"
}
```

And I'd like to return the key - value pair of that object in a React component like so:

```js
function MyFunc() {
  return (
   <div>
    {
      Object.keys(NewPerson).map((key) => (
        <div>{key}: {NewPerson[key]}</div>
      ))
     }
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, I can access they `key` but not its value. I have this error:

> TS: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Profile'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Profile'.

I've tried to use `Object.values` and `filter` but cannot fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b)

Comment: No, I don't think so. I've been reading the answer there but assigning keyof typeof in my case isn't an option. I only have 1 interface and 1 object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
interface Profile {
    name: string;
    title: string;
    [key: string]: string;
}
const NewPerson: Profile = {
    name: "John Smith",
    title: "Software Engineer"
}
function MyFunc() {
  return (
   <div>
    {
      Object.keys(NewPerson).map((key: keyof Profile) => (
        <div>{key}: {NewPerson[key]}</div>
      ))
     }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I got this error:
```
Argument of type '(key: "title" | "name") => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => Element'.
  Types of parameters 'key' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"title" | "name"'
```

Answer (score 5):

What about using Object.entries combined with a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, like this:

```
Object.entries(NewPerson).map(([key, value]) => {
   <div>{key}: {value}</div>
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but `forEach` doesn't work in React.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolved it like this:

```js
Object.entries(NewPerson).map(([key, value]) => {
 <div>{key}: {value}</div>
})
```