# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type - Phaser

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

I know this has been asked, but still can't figure out a solution for my case.

I have a file where I define certain values and then I was to loop thru them. I get the error in this part of the code

```
preloadImages(){
    this.load.setPath("./assets/images");
    for (const key in STATIC.IMAGES) {
        if (STATIC.IMAGES.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this.load.image(STATIC.IMAGES[key], STATIC.IMAGES[key]);                
        }
    }
}
```

The complain comes on the STATIC.IMAGES[key] calls.
And STATIC comes from a file with

```
export const STATIC = {

SCENES: {
    LOAD: "LOAD",
    MENU: "MENU"
},

IMAGES: {
    MENU_BG :"bg.png",
    MENU_TITLE: "title.png",
    MENU_PLAY: "play.png",
    MENU_SETTINGS: "settings.png",
    MENU_CREDITS: "credits.png",
    MENU_SPEAKER: "speaker.png",
    MENU_SPEAKER_MUTE: "speaker_mute.png"
},

SPRITES: {
    LOOP: { 
        name: "loop.png",
        size: 64
    }
},

AUDIOS: {
    BG_MUSIC: "airtone.mp3",
    POP: "pop.mp3",
    WOOSH: "woosh.mp3"
}};
```

Not sure I understand why this happens and how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's pare that down into a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Feel free to replace `obj` below with your `STATIC.IMAGES`; it's the same explanation either way:

```
let obj = { a: "hey", b: "you", c: "guys" };

for (const k in obj) {
  console.log(obj[k].toUpperCase()); // error!
  /* Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 
  'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; }'. */
}
```

Here we have an object `obj` with three keys.  We try to iterate over those keys with a `for..in` loop and we get an error that you can't use `k` to index into `obj`.  Why?  Isn't that the point of `for..in` loops?

---

The problem here is that object types in TypeScript are *open* or *extendible*, and not *closed* or *exact*.  You can add extra properties to an object in TypeScript without violating its type.  This is great in some situations: it allows you to extend interfaces and subclass classes by adding properties.  But in other situations it's a pain:

The compiler sees `obj` as a value of type `{a: string, b: string, c: string}`.  Since this type is not exact, when you do `for (const k in obj)`, the compiler knows that `k` will take on values `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`, but it *doesn't* know that those are the only possible values:

```
let hmm = { a: "hey", b: "you", c: "guys", d: 12345 };
obj = hmm; // no error!
```

There's no error in `obj = hmm` because the value `hmm` matches `{a: string, b: string, c: string}`.  The `d` property does not violate the type.  So, for all the compiler knows, `for (const k in obj)` will enumerate `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, and *who knows what other `string` values*.  Therefore, the type of `k` is not `keyof typeof obj`.  It is just `string`.

And it's not safe to index into `{a: string, b: string, c: string}` with a key of type `string`.  Indeed, with `hmm` assigned to `obj`, there will be a runtime error calling `(12345).toUpperCase()`.  So it's correct, if not very useful, for the compiler to warn you.

See [microsoft/TypeScript#35847](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35847) for an "official" version of the answer to this question.  Also see [Why doesn't `Object.keys()` return a `keyof` type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript), which is the same question except using `Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => ...)` instead of `for (const k in obj) {...}`... and it has the same answer.

If exact types are ever introduced, then maybe this problem would just go away. There is a feature request for this: [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  But it doesn't look like this is going to happen any time soon.

---

For now, then, what can be done?  Well, if we know for sure that `obj` won't have any extra keys that the compiler doesn't know about, we can treat it as if it were an exact type and just tell the compiler not to worry about it.  This "telling the compiler" takes the form of a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
for (const k in obj) {
  console.log(obj[k as keyof typeof obj].toUpperCase()); // okay
}
```

Here, `k as keyof typeof obj` is the type assertion.  We have to be careful not to lie to the compiler this way, but as long as we *are* careful, then it's fine.

---

For completeness you can also declare `k` outside the loop and give it a narrower type; this is equivalent to the type assertion in terms of type safety:

```
let k: keyof typeof obj;
for (k in obj) {
  console.log(obj[k as keyof typeof obj].toUpperCase()); // okay
}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgVhAvBA3hAhgLggIgBYgCeOANBDNjoVAK6kQDGlA5jYQM44QC+A3ALAAoIaEh4AtuKSoMlAsTIVc1OmSa5WHegBNsARgBMAZgAsAVh4DBsBMgnjeEAPROIAOygQQAJ29RvAIRCQgBm-hAAFAxQbuyQANYQAJZu0PAAlDJCEIwx7FCgAHTAUMwRNgDa8QC6hWBQAKoADk0+AMLo7CAR6emOLl6+-kGCOU4AVBAAoqDiIG6QSeJNwEkMSWDAhBB4nRipAOToboQHEGCEreQgDOg0XV4AHk3eIOzsSTHQIeeXIBDZCAHOLeFLMM63NwHSAwf73EDac6eFLaECPX5XA5oLAQEFgxxKPFuZiOdREkk8A6FCDjJxCbjBQRhbyRaKxBLJVI2TIoQFs-JFEplSqJPbxIhQH4XVqStJwWr1ZqtbwdLo9PrOVxQeLoQj0xmiCDxbDi6hSv6ymxWZmRRIpOU8vl5AogYqlcrwKoYdhGiXmmU-GwKxotdqdbq9fpanV6wQMwRAA)