# TypeScript index object with string inside a loop

Tags: typescript

My issue has already been [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b). My case, however, is slightly different and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

```
type Filters = {
  short: boolean;
  long: boolean;
};
```

Then in my function:

```
const options = {short: false, long: true}
{Object.keys(options).map((option, i) => (
  <Text>{options[option]}</Text>
  ...
```

I understand that TypeScript cannot use a string as a keyof an object.
I tried using the solutions in the thread I mentioned, but I'm getting various errors. I am not quite sure how to use those solutions in my case of a loop. Any ideas?

Comment: An alternative would be using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/entries) or [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/values). `Object.entries(options).map(([key, value]) => {})`

Comment: @known-as-bmf not really. I am getting the same error since key will inherit exactly the same type (string) as using Object.keys

Comment: Yes but you won't have to do `options[key]` anymore since the value will already provided in the callback.

Comment: @known-as-bmf I see what you mean. This is indeed a possible alternative. In my case it would not work. I abstracted my code for clarity reasons, but I actually NEED to use the key because I'm using it on a different object. ie: ```Object.keys(options).map((option, i) => (<Text>{anotherObject[option]}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the `Object.keys` return type:

```
(Object.keys(options) as Array<keyof typeof options>)
   .map((option, i) => console.log(options[option]));
```

as mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string).

Comment: Thank you! Just one adjustment - ```as Array<keyof typeof options>``` will throw a warning. Use ```as (keyof typeof options)[]``` instead