# How to handle any as parameter type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to use this generic helper function to create form data:

```js
function createFormData(data: any): FormData {
  const formData = new FormData();

  for (const key in data) {
    formData.append(key, data[key]);
  }

  return formData;
}
```

But the ESLint gives me an `unexpected any` warning.
When I change the parameter type `any` to `object` it shows me the following error message for `data[key]`:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

How can I fix my code here in order that no error messages or warnings are shown (without just turning off the linter)?

Comment: Duplicate of [Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b)

Comment: @GuyIncognito I don't think it's a duplicate. I'm asking explicitly for function parameter handling and how to surpress the ESLint warning for the usage of any

Answer (score 0):

Instead of any you could provide the  value data type also

```
function createFormData(data: {[key: string]: any}): FormData {
  const formData = new FormData();

  for (const key in data) {
    formData.append(key, data[key]);
  }

  return formData;
}
```

Comment: The ESLint warning `unexpected any` is still shown

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-grass-olpe8

Comment: So you are telling me, because they did it in that example project, it's the right way to go?

Comment: This is what i have created, also i think you need to define type for you data and if it throws error for using key as a string you might have to add the type of keys as string

Comment: The `key: string` part is fine. But it shows a warning because of the `any` keyword.

Comment: for that you you can provide the type i suppose for you it would be sting only 
{[key: string] :string}

Comment: But let's say I want to override the `console.log` function which takes `...data: any`. How can I achieve that?