# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript, list, object

**I am unable to add elements in my object in typescript.**

```
const bodyData = [
  {
    propName: "name",
    value: "secondName",
  },
  {
    propName: "surname",
    value: "nothing",
  },
];

const updatedData = {};

bodyData.forEach(({ propName, value }) => (updatedData[propName] = value));

console.log(updatedData);
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

14 bodyData.forEach(({ propName, value }) => (updatedData[propName] = value));
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

at createTSError (/home/mycomputer/MyTrailProjects/typescript-rest-shop/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:513:12)
at reportTSError (/home/mycomputer/MyTrailProjects/typescript-rest-shop/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:517:19)
at getOutput (/home/mycomputer/MyTrailProjects/typescript-rest-shop/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:752:36)
at Object.compile (/home/mycomputer/MyTrailProjects/typescript-rest-shop/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:968:32)
at Module.m._compile (/home/mycomputer/MyTrailProjects/typescript-rest-shop/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1056:42)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/mycomputer/MyTrailProjects/typescript-rest-shop/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1059:12)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b)

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare type for `updateData` like this:

```
const updatedData: {
  [key: string]: string;
} = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this either:

```
const updatedData: Record<string, string> = {};
```

or set:

```
"noImplicitAny": true
```

in `tsconfig.json`