# Typescript How to type the sort column for an object in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, preact

In a React *(Preact, actually)* class, I wish to sort columns of data when I click the header title for the column.

**Here is the interface that defines the data columns:**

```
interface AllExisting {
  id: number;
  date: string;
  short: string;
  original: string;
}
```

**Here is the function that does the sort:**

```
const doSortColumn = (a: AllExisting, b: AllExisting) => {
  if (typeof a[sortColumn] === 'string') {
    return a[sortColumn]?.localeCompare(b[sortColumn]);
  } else if (a[sortColumn] !== undefined) {
    return +a[sortColumn] - +b[sortColumn];
  }
};
```

**Here's the line that calls the function:**

```
allExisting.sort(doSortColumn).map((r) => <TableRow row={r} onEdit={this.handleEdit} />)}
```

#### The Problem:

The error message on `a[sortColumn]` and `b[sortColumn]` within the function reads:
 `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AllExisting'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'AllExisting'. ts(7053)`  [image: view error message]

#### Here's some of the many things I've tried:

`if (typeof a[(sortColumn as string | undefined)] === 'string') {` [image: error3]

`a[(sortColumn as any)]` [image: view error message]

Even removing the type test and just using `if (sortColumn !== undefined) {` still returns the error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AllExisting'` *(click image for larger)*
[image: error4]

#### Desired Outcome:

I would prefer to type this properly, but I am also open to just disabling typescript in this function (how would I do that?).

*Thanks!*

### Update:

[This answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b) appears to contain magic solutions, but I can't quite work out the correct incantation.  This looked the most promising:

[image: attempt 71]

which seemed to work, but now the line that displays the rows has these two errors:

[image: attempt 71e1]

and

[image: attempt 71e2]

Comment: Make `sortColumn` a `keyof AllExisting` instead of `string`.