# implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class like this:

```
interface UserProps {
  name: string
  age: number
}

export class User {
  constructor(private data: UserProps) {}

  get(propName: string): number | string {
    return this.data[propName]
  }
}
```

and I don't know why I get this error: "**Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'UserProps'.

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'UserProps'**"

any advice?

Comment: It means that you never check what `propName` is but you're using it to access a property from `UserProps`. So if `propName = "foo"` TS has no way of knowing what would be returned from `this.data[propName]`. Therefore, it implicitly assigns it `any`. [Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57086672)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error occurs because you can't use any `string` as the key, only a subset (`name` and `age`). Set `keyof UserProps` as the type for `propName`:

```
interface UserProps {
  name: string
  age: number
}

export class User {
  constructor(private data: UserProps) {}

  get<T extends keyof UserProps>(propName: T): UserProps[T] {
    return this.data[propName]
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't enough of an improvement, IMO - `user.get("age")` still returns `number | string` which is misleading, at the very least.

Comment: @VLAZ I think this is a good solution however I think this error should not happen.

Comment: @ehsan it's your code that is sloppy. For it to work, TS also has to be sloppy. Which causes an error. The solution is not good *enough* because the resulting type doesn't necessarily match what it should be. That's what I was highlighting.