# typescript fonts for object invocation

Tags: reactjs, typescript

error message:"

"The element is implicitly of type "any" because an expression of type "string" cannot be used for indexing of type "IColorPokemonObj".
No index signature found in type "IColorPokemonObj" with parameter of type "string" .ts (7053)"

```
<SubPopupPokemonImg styleBackground={{background: colorPokemonObj?.[type1]}}>



export const colorPokemonObj: IColorPokemonObj = {
   fire : '#D93E30',
   grass : '#7AC74C',
   electric : '#f2cb07',             
   water:'#35BAFF',
   ground:'#E2BF65',
   rock:'#B6A136',
   fairy: '#D685AD',
   poison: '#64D368',
   bug: '#A6B91A',
   dragon:'#6F35FC',
   psychic:'#F95587',
   flying:'#A98FF3' ,
   fighting:'#C22E28' ,
   normal:'#A8A77A' ,
   ice:'#96D9D6' ,
   ghost:'#735797' ,
   dark: '#705746' ,
   unknown: '#B7B7CE'
}


export interface IColorPokemonObj {
  fire: string;
  grass: string;
  electric: string;
  water: string;
  ground: string;
  rock: string;
  fairy: string;
  poison: string;
  bug: string;
  dragon: string;
  psychic: string;
  flying: string;
  fighting: string;
  'normal': string ,
  'ice': string ,
  'ghost':string ,
  'dark': string,
  'unknown': string
}
```

if you pass the call signature, then immediately yields the type any and error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b)

Answer (score 0):

To ensure type safety, typescript won't let you use any string to index your objects - you can only use actual keys of IColorPokemonObj.

You can change the type of your key `type1`:

```
let key1: string = 'fire';
const fireColorERROR = colorPokemonObj[key1];

let key2: keyof IColorPokemonObj = 'fire';
const fireColorOK = colorPokemonObj[key2];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.7.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGEIAbaABQgGtgBbCJAeQCMArOAbwCg450EowAFxwAzjCjIA5gG4ecKVEyjRI8ZKSz5wEsGwSE2NQc1zeAd0yooxjVt6KIAVyQATW9LNwoEbFQ+m8lgCAJ4B9nCQCKIM4V7MTlJx8q5KUrFiJhFgoiHYABaGybzoJCHSxXwIUvkwFZl2XgDkSNC0mCRN4XAANPJNhsBdDdK9-TUQ4l3qo328Ta6YUFTDM5pzcE0uVK3mSKtZXAC+XFygkLBw2AziV6QU1HQMLKwiRPdQlDT0TGxwALyceRVQRwERNADEABEAJwAZgAonCAAxNDYKJQqMGbCEAdgAgoRcQAWQho4E6PQGbDYyHoABM2GYyNxaN47I5HOBlmsQkhcIArAAhfEAMVF5PZjhc7khCPpQtFADYBZLeD4-HyIUKlfiAIxwpVqviYULg6FKgAcAvxUONURiSHNSuJUMNluNCSSOPxSqFML1+ONqUw6SdkKVosForJ6JyeUKRkhophAoFltZ6NK5U0WvxMMt4rhTTG7P4NTquchhHp9PlHtLvFaUHaJDzlvxuIJJfRgy1MKVsKhRsbCnykxgWtxgtxMNZo8Wy3NuORApJI-R212TpxQtxe8ICKax1Op108BoIT13UBTX4giacmuSFu9+AxDIUARACVv4xvwCdyfl8Ty-KwADal56gAunIXDnnAl70iIl4QOgBAfg83zPH8t5vo+XDPq+Ajvh8jAANKAdcwGPD8LyQcAIT0rBXBAA)

There is also a feature called [Index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) which allows you to use any string as a key (which is useful when you don't know the shape of the object, but in your case the shape is well defined and you know all property names in advance)

Comment: The "string" type cannot be assigned to the "keyof IColorPokemonObj" type

Comment: the error has now changed to a different value
I do not understand what's going on (