# Get Object Value by Dynamic key in Vue js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have this typescript data in a config file:

```
const filtersTracking = {
  [SEARCH_TYPE_ARTICLES]: {
    orderBy: {
        category: 'Suche Filter Rechtstipps',
        action: 'Sortierung Auswahl',
    },
    practiceAreas: {
      category: 'Suche Filter Rechtstipps',
      action: 'Rechtsgebiet Auswahl',
    },
    ratingAverage: {
      category: 'Suche Filter Rechtstipps',
      action: 'Bewertung Sterne',
    },
    ratingCount: {
      category: 'Suche Filter Rechtstipps',
      action: 'Anzahl Bewertungen',
    },
    publicationYear: {
      category: 'Suche Filter Rechtstipps',
      action: 'Publikation',
    },
    isGuide: {
      category: 'Suche Filter Rechtstipps',
      action: 'Ratgeber',
    },
    hasVideo: {
      category: 'Suche Filter Rechtstipps',
      action: 'Video',
    },
    internationalLaws: {
      category: 'Suche Filter Rechtstipps',
      action: 'Internationales Recht',
    },
  },
}
```

what I am trying to do is to get 'category' and 'action' data, I have tried following methods but none worked for me:

1. filtersTracking[SEARCH_TYPE_ARTICLES][key]
2. filtersTracking[SEARCH_TYPE_ARTICLES].key
3. filtersTracking[SEARCH_TYPE_ARTICLES].[key]

here 'key' is a dynamic variable and I am getting the data key(e.g 'orderBy' or 'practiceArea') inside 'key'.

```
public function(key) {
console.log(filtersTracking[SEARCH_TYPE_ARTICLES][key])
}
```

Comment: "none worked for me" What is the error message? What is the value of the variable `SEARCH_TYPE_ARTICLES`? Is it defined when you call it?

Comment: BTL, export const SEARCH_TYPE_USERS = 'users'; 

error  message : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment `BTL, export const SEARCH_TYPE_USERS = 'users'; error message : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type`

This post should help you:

[Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to inde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b)

Comment: ThankYou so much bro, that post helped me out. So, we can do it like this 

filtersTracking[SEARCH_TYPE_ARTICLES][key as keyof typeof filtersTracking]

Comment: No probs, please set this as an answer if it solves your issue