# How do I assign class properties values based on existing keys in an object I send?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class

```
export class Example {
    id: number = 0;
    a: string = '';
    b: string = '';

    constructor(data: any) {
        Object.keys(data).filter(key => key in data).forEach((key: string) => this[key] = data[key]);
        return this;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to send an object in the constructor, and based on that object it will assign the values in which the key matches the property of the class. This is because I might send an object which has additional key properties, but I do not want to put in my class the values that are not defined in my class. This is why I don't use `Object.assign(this, data);` because it will add additional properties to my class if the data object has them.

The problem with the code in the constructor above is that it's not letting me use `this[key]`, the error being `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Example'`. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Unrelated but `key in data` should be `key in this`.

Comment: True. I changed it thinking that was the problem (don’t ask why I thought that).

Comment: try this `.forEach((key: string) => this[key as keyof this] = data[key])`  this question may provide some insight https://stackoverflow.com/a/69198602/12036671

Comment: Yes! It worked, thank you! If you add this as an answer I'll gladly accept it.