# How to declare type in typescript properly

Tags: typescript, angular13

I am getting below the error in my code.

```
let getVal: string
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AppComponent'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'AppComponent'.ts(7053)
```

So, How to resolve like this type declaration issue in typescript.If anyone knows please help to resolve.

app.component.html:

```
<button *ngFor="let season of seasons" (click)="show(season)">
  {{ season }}
</button>

<div *ngIf="group1">Group 1 content</div>

<div *ngIf="group2">Group 2 content</div>

<div *ngIf="group3">Group 3 content</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
  seasons = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3'];
  group1: boolean = false;
  group2: boolean = false;
  group3: boolean = false;

  show(val: string) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < this.seasons.length; i++) {
      if (this.seasons[i] === val) {
        let getVal = val.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, ''); 
        this[getVal] = true; // getting error here
      } else {
        let getVal = this.seasons[i].toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, ''); 
        this[getVal] = false; // getting error here
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: check this below link may be you will find answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b

Comment: @white_shadow: Already i have seen that link, But i am not able to find the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use `(this as any)[getVal] = ...`.

However, I would recommend doing something like this:

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

    readonly groups: { [key: string]: boolean } = {};

    seasons = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3'];

    show(val: string) { 
        for (let i = 0; i < this.seasons.length; i++) {
            if (this.seasons[i] === val) {
                const getVal = val.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, ''); 
                this.groups[getVal] = true;
            } else {
                const getVal = this.seasons[i].toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
                this.groups[getVal] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This isolates the "groups" from the rest of the component's class members and allows you to iterate, add, and remove elements without having to mess around with type casting, e.g.

```
Object.keys(this.groups).forEach(
    group => console.log(`${group}=${this.groups[group]}`);
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button *ngFor="let season of seasons" (click)="show(season)">
  {{ season }}
</button>

<div *ngIf="groups.group1">Group 1 content</div>

<div *ngIf="groups.group2">Group 2 content</div>

<div *ngIf="groups.group3">Group 3 content</div>
```

*(or render groups dynamically)*

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let entry of groups | keyvalue">
    <div *ngIf="!!entry.value">
        {{ group.key }} content
    </div>
</ng-container>
```