# How do I tell typescript to use string as key of a intersection type?

Tags: typescript

Initially my code was :

```js
type Point = {
    x: number, y: number
};

type Point3D = Point & {
    z: number
}
function printPoint(p: Point | Point3D) {
    log("Point {");
    for (const coordinate in p) {
        log("\t", p[coordinate])
    }
    log("}")
}
printPoint({ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 })
printPoint({ x: 0.4, y: 4 })
```

which would cause the error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type ..`  to which I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69198602/6591533.

There they suggest to use `as keyof Type` after your index to get rid of the error :

```js
// This works
for (const coordinate in p) {
        log("\t", p[coordinate as keyof Point])
   }
// This does not
for (const coordinate in p) {
        log("\t", p[coordinate as keyof Point3D])
    }
// Neither this
for (const coordinate in p) {
        log("\t", p[coordinate as keyof Point | Point3D])
    }
```

Comment: What's `log()`? Could you make your code a [mre]?

Comment: Where is the "intersection type" in this question?  `Point | Point3D` is a *union type*, not an intersection type.

Comment: Are you just asking how to write `keyof (Point | Point3D)`?  That is, is this about syntax?

Comment: @jcalz it's just console.log, intersection type is Point3D and yes `keyof (Point | Point3D)` is exactly what I wanted to write

Comment: Hmm, the question seems to be asking "how to I write `keyof` on the type `Point | Point3D`" which is a union type.  I guess `Point3D` is an intersection type, but you could write `interface Point3D extends Point { z: number }` and it changes nothing about your question.  Intersection types seem to be a red herring here.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generics and let typescript infer your parameter's type.

```
type Point = {
    x: number, y: number
};

type Point3D = Point & {
    z: number
}
function printPoint<T>(p: T) {
    console.log("Point {");
    
    for (const coordinate in p) {
        console.log("\t", p[coordinate])
    }

    console.log("}")
}

printPoint({ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 })
printPoint({ x: 0.4, y: 4 })
```

Check this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbCgXigbwFBT1ADwC4okBXAWwCMIAnAGihBPOruwF8BubbUSWIhQBmACLpByVADIsufAC8WlGrU7YAZmSQBjYAjhIoYWlPhSAPABUAfAAowJKwEo5%20KDsMBnOABsIAHS%20cADmdgBE5ihY4c487vJ4GnC0UHaeSF6onikAJsgAhsDQyMauOO7uGT7%20QaERADrA4YxgANo5tPlIRRAAus6JUBy8Vd5%20gcFh4Ryx6tgmZkLAdpiEJACMjMxQAEyMSlDCw4OLKFEra8RQAAwBACzbJPcnQA)

**Update:** you can narrow your type like -

```
function printPoint<T extends Point | Point3D>(p: T) {}
```