# TypeScript Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript, react-native, error-handling, typeof

My code is just warning fine, but I'm facing an Error type from Ts while accessing an element in the object using string.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const categoriesResult: CategoryResult[] = Object.values(
      questions?.reduce((r, e) => {
        const k = e.category.id;
        if (!r[k as keyof object])
          return r[k].totalCount += 1;
      }, {})
    );
    setCategories(categoriesResult);
  }, [questions]);
```

The error is in r[k] to be more specific.

Thanks

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot going on here so I will unpack this line by line.

First, let's ignore useEffect.

Next, the assignment:

```
const categoriesResult: CategoryResult[] = Object.values(
```

This looks fine `Object.values` will return an array, and you expect those to be `CategoryResult` type.

Ok, let's tackle the entire reduce block:

```
questions?.reduce((r, e) => {
  const k = e.category.id;
  if (!r[k as keyof object])
    return r[k].totalCount += 1;
}, {})
```

Your array of questions is to be reduced to an object `{}`.

First issue, you need to return `r` always, so let's make the code this:

```
questions?.reduce((r, e) => {
  const k = e.category.id;
  if (!r[k as keyof object]) {
    r[k].totalCount += 1;
  }
  return r
},{})
```

Without returning r you will not reduce, you will have an empty object.

Next, `r`, starts it's life being equal to `{}` - an object - hence the error - string can't be used to index type `{}`

There is some valid code below for what you are trying to achieve, in this code, the type of `{}` is set explicitly so that it knows the object has string keys, and values of CategoryResult types:

```
// The result type
type CategoryResult = {
  totalCount: number;
};

// Some example questions
const questions = [
  {
    category: {
      id: "How should this work?",
    },
  },
  {
    category: {
      id: "Does that make sense?",
    },
  },
  {
    category: {
      id: "Does that make sense?",
    },
  },
];

// A count on questions
const questionCounts = questions?.reduce(
  (r, e) => {
    const k = e.category.id;

    if (r[k] === undefined) {
      r[k] = {
        totalCount: 1,
      };
    } else {
      r[k].totalCount += 1;
    }

    return r;
  },
  // The type of the questions count accumulator in the reduce
  {} as Record<string, CategoryResult>
);

const categoriesResult: CategoryResult[] = Object.values(questionCounts);

console.info("result", { categoriesResult });
```