# Typescript is giving error. Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript

I have an object like this:

```
const obj = {
  user_name: 'user2',
  user_desc: 'desc 2',
};
```

Now I'm calling an onClick function that specifies which parameter to get from the object

```
function myFunction(key_name: string) {
  // as my constant is of type object, I can get data from keys as
  console.log(obj[key_name]);
}
```

My function is running fine but typescript is giving me an error

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'

How do I go about getting rid of this error?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an interface to describe your data shape

```
interface Obj {
  user_name: string;
  user_desc: string;
}

const obj: Obj = {
  user_name: 'user2',
  user_desc: 'desc 2',
};

function myFunction(key_name: keyof Obj) {
  console.log(obj[key_name]);
}

myFunction('user_name');
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the `obj` that you have created, the keys are inferred by typescript.

There are two ways of solving this:

1. Give type to the `obj`

```
const obj: Record<string, string> = {
 user_name: 'user2',
 user_desc: 'desc 2'
}
```

---- OR -----

2. Give type to your function param

```
function myFunction (key_name : keyof typeof obj) {
 console.log(obj[key_name])
}
```