# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror

I got the following code that was a JS code and tried to convert it to a TS code:

```
const toCamelCase = (rows: any[]) => {
  return rows.map((row) => {
    const replaced = {};

    for (let key in row) {
      const camelCase = key.replace(/([-_][a-z])/gi, ($1) =>
        $1.toUpperCase().replace('_', '')
      );
      replaced[camelCase] = row[key];
    }

    return replaced;
  });
};
```

But I get the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)
```

Here:

```
  replaced[camelCase] = row[key];
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This should help you, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need add [index signature](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures) to your `replaced` object
like:

```
const replaced:{[index:string]:string} = {};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `replaced[camelCase]`?