# Calling a function located in typescript file A from another typescript file B

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following code that is not executing properly

platform.tsx

```
  import { windowHelper } from "./windowHelper";
import { officeHelper } from "./officeHelper";
import { googleHelper } from "./googleHelper";
export class platformHelper {
 
    static callFCT = (fnctname: any, fnctparams = null) => {
        const platform = window.localStorage ? window.localStorage.getItem('platform') : "office";
        var fn: any = null;
        var wndhelper:any = new windowHelper();
        var offhelper:any = new officeHelper();
        var gghelper:any = new googleHelper();
        switch (platform) {
            case "window":
                fn = wndhelper[fnctname];
                break;
            case "office":
               
                fn = offhelper[fnctname];
                console.log(fn); //return undefined
                console.log(fnctname);
                break;
            case "google":
                fn = gghelper[fnctname];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        // is object a function?
        if (typeof fn === "function") fn.apply(null, fnctparams);
    }
}
```

OfficeHelper.tsx

```
    export class officeHelper {
  constructor() { }
static GetEmail = () => {
    return Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress;
  }
}
```

login.tsx

```
 let userEmailAddress = platformHelper.callFCT("GetEmail"); 
 console.log(userEmailAddress ) // UNDEFINED
```

The `fn` function is always undefined and the email address is not being returned as `GetEmail` is not being called

Comment: the `callFCT("GetEmail")` run the function which doesn't have return so you have undefined. You forget return

Comment: fn.apply should call GetEmail and GetEmail should return the email with  > return Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress;

Comment: yes, it return the value in the `if`, but this same result isn't return in callFCT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `GetEmail` is a [`static`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#static-members) function of `officeHelper` class, so you have to access it through `officeHelper.GetEmail` (or `officeHelper["GetEmail"]`), instead of `new officeHelper().GetEmail`.

Then, as pointed out in the question comments and other answers, do not forget to return the result of `fn.apply`.

Comment: noted but i am getting the following error: Element implicitly has an any type because expression of type any can't be used to index type typeof officeHelper

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b

Answer (score 0):

callFCT doesnt return value.
Add return in callFCT

```
 // ...
     if (typeof fn === "function") {
        return fn(fnctparams)
     };
 // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to return the content from the executed method. You should do:

```
static callFCT = (fnctname: any, fnctparams = null) => {
    const platform = window.localStorage ? window.localStorage.getItem('platform') : "office";
    var fn: any = null;
    var wndhelper:any = new windowHelper();
    var offhelper:any = new officeHelper();
    var gghelper:any = new googleHelper();
    switch (platform) {
        case "window":
            fn = wndhelper[fnctname];
            break;
        case "office":
           
            fn = offhelper[fnctname];
            console.log(fn); //return undefined
            console.log(fnctname);
            break;
        case "google":
            fn = gghelper[fnctname];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (typeof fn === "function")
       return fn.apply(null, fnctparams); // return the result of GetEmail
    return null; // no function -> return nothing
}
```

Comment: i understand but in my case `if (typeof fn === "function")` should return true but instead it is returning undefined so callFct willl always return null, i am not sure why