# Filter a JSON array with a string search on any property: TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a Json object array which I am binding to a grid.

**`I want to filter the JSON array and return only those objects whose properties' values have a matching keyword as that of an input string.`**

This is my sample JSON

```
[{
      "TransactionID": "1",
      "MyProperty1": "some data 1",
      "MyProperty2": "28-02-2023",
      "MyProperty3": "some more data 1",
      "MyProperty4": "some other data 1",
      "documents": [
                      {"TransactionID": "1","MyProperty1":"Document 1","MyProperty2":"Completed"},
                      {"TransactionID": "1","MyProperty1":"Document 2","MyProperty2":"In Progress"},
                      {"TransactionID": "1","MyProperty1":"Document 3","MyProperty2":"In Progress"}
                   ]
    }, 
    {
      "TransactionID": "2",
      "MyProperty1": "some data 2",
      "MyProperty1": "27-02-2023",
      "MyProperty1": "some more data 2",
      "MyProperty1": "some other data 2",
      "documents":  [ 
                       {"TransactionID": "2","MyProperty1":"Document 1","MyProperty1":"Completed"},
                       {"TransactionID": "2","MyProperty1":"Document 2","MyProperty1":"Completed"}
                    ]
    }];
```

I have tried doing this, but throws this error `'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'`

```
    doFilter(filterText: string) {
    
   let filteredObject = this.engagementData.filter(o =>
      Object.keys(o).some(k => o[k].toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase())));
       
  }
```

Here my data has the above JSON.

Can someone suggest if there is something I am missing?

I am aware that looping through each property of each of the JSON Object is one of the options

but it will be helpful if there are any inbuilt functions which can retrieve all objects from JSON which has a specific string in any of the object's property

Comment: What's the (inferred or declared) type of `this.engagementData`?

Comment: it is an Object[], the engagementData will have the JSON data that I've provided in the OP

Comment: Then `o[k]` cannot be guaranteed to be a `string`. Indeed, if when `k` is `"documents"`, `o[k]` will be an array, and you can't call `toLowerCase()` on that.

Comment: that makes sense, but is there a way to exclude the search on the documents property or even better would be to include documents as well.

Comment: yes, using something like: 
Object.keys(o).some(k => JSON.stringify(o[k]).toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase())));

Comment: @JuanCastillo I tried your code, it still gives me this error 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object''

Comment: @Shekar.gvr it works for me. Can you check this replit?
https://replit.com/@JuanCastillo18/EachHomelyBusiness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `this.engagementData` is of type `object`, then you can't call a `string` method on it, so you can't call `.toLowerCase()`on it, and that's what the error is telling you.

And if you are trying to filter `objects` which have a property matching your searched text then you should check on all `values` of that `object`:

```
let filteredObject = this.engagementData.filter(o =>
    Object.keys(o).some(k => Object.values(o[k]).some(val => val.toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase())));
```

You need to call `toLowerCase()` and `.includes()` on each value of the `o[k]` object `properties`, instead of `o[k]`.

**Note:**

This is the case for `object` types, if `o[k]` can be of type `array` or other types, you need to check over the type of `o[k]` and adapt the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your error is the same of this answer
[Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b)

You need to specify the type of k

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).