# Use key value to look up variable when doing import as namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-import

Perhaps what I'm asking to do is impossible, or I'm taking the wrong approach but is it possible to use a string to do a lookup on an imported namespace?

If I have a file: `my_file.ts` and its contents are many of these:

```
export const MyThing: CustomType = {
    propertyOne: "name",
    propertyTwo: 2
}
export const AnotherThing: CustomType = {
    propertyOne: "Another",
    propertyTwo: 3
}
```

Then I have a file that is going to import all these, but needs to find and use them dynamically based on a string:

```
import * as allthings from "dir/folder/my_file"


function doStuff() {
   let currentThing = allthings['MyThing']; // works
   let name = 'MyThing';
   let currentThing2 = allthings[name]; // doesnt work

}
```

The error I get here is:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof
> import("dir/folder/my_file")'. No index signature with a parameter of
> type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("dir/folder/my_file")'.

Why does the literal string work but not a variable of type string?

Comment: The type of `name` is `string`. See what happens when you change `let name` to `const name`.

Comment: or `let name: keyof typeof allthings = 'MyThing'`

Comment: @zenly That's better than my answer to cast with `as const`

Comment: You don't want `keyof typeof` here because the value will be a union of all the property values. Just use `const name = 'MyThing"`

Comment: `keyof typeof allthings` is exactly equal to `"MyThing" | "AnotherThing"`. "Find and use them *dynamically* based on a string" implies that the string is not a constant in the actual use case.

Comment: @AluanHaddad OP mentions the string is dynamic, not a constant, otherwise they wouldn't use bracket syntax.

Comment: @Bergi I see what you mean

Answer (score 3):

The literal string doesn't work because someone could reassign any string to your `let name` variable.

It will work if your string is `const`. Casting it is possible:

```
let name = 'MyThing' as const;
```

But you should just define a `const` variable which has the same effect. There's no reason to define a variable with `let` unless you intend to change it.

```
const name = 'MyThing';
```

See this [TS playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQFQBYEswHMIwLwwDeAUDDALICeamWAXDAIwA0pMAmiAK4BON2DFsQC+xYgDMuYYFHTgYAExABlKF3HiAFAEoibGAgCmsYLx6GwUflnzwk1iAG0A5FWvOAugG4YAel8wAO4gPADWEPpGsGBwALaGtq7UGNjO8LigkFA++pnQMDHxAEyJnLzuOWQGxjCmPOaW1iUEiCgpOI6Fht5+AUqGEJZBIaGRNXUNVu0AzLatDp1xhkU9-oogA0PBYSJiQA)

If you don't know the key ahead of time, then if all the objects in `my_file` are of the same type (`CustomType`), then you can safely use `keyof typeof allthings` as the type

```
export const allthings = {
  MyThing: {
    propertyOne: "name",
    propertyTwo: 2
  },
  AnotherThing: {
    propertyOne: "Another",
    propertyTwo: 3
  }
};

type CustomType = typeof allthings[keyof typeof allthings];


function getValue(key: keyof typeof allthings): CustomType {
    return allthings[key]; 
}
```

See [TS example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFsE8DMEsBsCmA6ALgZwFCIB4AcB7AJ1VAGMCA7dUgQ3nlQAtZKBzdUAXlAG9NQoALKQAKi3YAuPgMGg8RAnkQlIAeUqJpAIkq1wibQBpZghUpWoxAdwLSATLIC%20JwQEFKBZivGs20-jl5RWVVDS1QbQ8vJhVjU2CLVVFbaQBmZ0wnAG5MTCtlUABhAFcaAnBRSEKeAsQCaFB6RgkOAG0Aa0RIBtA63ubmP3QAXVy86BLKMlRYKlA2RFQANXoSxAAKLshpbd7%20xsHW9ABKaVLyyurEGSCiJZKiSiaGIfZ0Tu6x0Cy8impSAA3ejcBZLVbwdYbKKebxEXzsbQnbJAA)

For these enum like objects, you can use `satisfies Record<string, MyType>` to enforce they are all of the same type

```
interface CustomType {
  propertyOne: string,
  propertyTwo: number
}

const allthings = {
  MyThing: {
    propertyOne: "name",
    propertyTwo: 2
  },
  AnotherThing: {
    propertyOne: "Another",
    propertyTwo: 3
  }
} satisfies Record<string, CustomType>;


function getValueFromAllThings(key: keyof typeof allthings): CustomType {
    return allthings[key]; 
}
```

Comment: That's good, but you should indicate that the second form is preferable because it actually is constant meaning the type will in fact match the value in all cases

Comment: Hey Ruan, thanks for the reply! Unless I'm missing something your TS playground is just a simple dict array within the same file. The issue I was having was when I specifically wanted to dynamically look for a variable within the imported "namespace"

Comment: @user2616166 The issue you were having is not what you specified in your question, your question says that you know exactly which string you're going to bracket access. It does not matter that they're in a separate file. If the exact string is not known by the compiler, it won't work, you will need to cast it manually to whatever key you want.

Comment: 1) Seems like your little tool is curried, so the doc comments should be changed to reflect that: https://tsplay.dev/WGdY9w 2) This tool also doesn't seem that useful anymore since `satisfies` exists now: https://tsplay.dev/WYQybW

Comment: @zenly I had never thought of combining `Record` with `satisfies` this way. Thanks, I'll update the post to use that...

Comment: @user2616166 I wrote a function that given one of the keys in your `allthings`, it returns the corresponding object. `getValueFromAllThings('MyThing')` I am unsure of what you mean by dynamic. Your question still doesn't show your example where the string is dynamic. As I've explained, if the string is fully dynamic, you can't guarantee the shape of the object you're retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

I reread a similar question here: [Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b)

And was finally able to get it to work by doing this:

```
import * as allthings from "dir/folder/my_file"


function doStuff() {
   let currentThing = allthings['MyThing']; // works
   let name = 'MyThing';
   let currentThing2 = allthings[name as keyof typeof allthings]; // does work

}
```

Comment: This only works if every sub-object is the same shape, if they are of different shapes, it will be an OR of all the shapes under `allthings`.

Comment: Don't use a type assertion on a `string`-typed variable (`name`), but rather declare it with that type in the first place: `let name: keyof typeof allthings = 'MyThing';`

Comment: @RuanMendes the objects are all the same shape hence they call of type CustomType.

Comment: @user2616166  What @Bergi suggested does work: `let name: keyof typeof allthings = 'MyThing'`. Also. I don't see anything dynamically accessing a key in an object??? Please do not mark this as the accepted answer since it doesn't show much.

Comment: @user2616166 There is no guarantee from the compiler point of view that they are all of the same shape. My answer shows how to provide that guarantee.

Comment: @user2616166 "*i cant say `var = 'MyThing'` as i dont know "mything" at this point, its dynamically finding the key in the object.*" - then please adjust the code in your question to show how you are dynamically finding the key. I assumed that you would simply replace the `'MyThing'` with a more dynamic expression, which doesn't change how `name` should be declared.