# How to access object properties without: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a deepEquals method with options like escapeProps: string[] and anyValueProps[] to allow a non-strict comparison.

My issue is that don't know anything in advance about the types of the objects I'll get to compare. TypeScript complains with the error (**a[key] being underlined as incorrect**):

```
test/extend/sameObjects.ts:100:45 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

100     if (!keysB.includes(key) || !deepEquals(a[key] as object, b[key] as object)) {
```

This is my code:

```
function deepEquals(a: object, b: object): boolean {
  // Handle null values
  if (a === null && b === null) {
    return true;
  }

  // Check if types are different
  if (typeof a !== typeof b) {
    return false;
  }

  // Handle non-object types
  if (typeof a !== "object") {
    return a === b;
  }

  // Handle arrays
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    const aArray = a as object[];
    const bArray = b as object[];

    if (!Array.isArray(bArray) || aArray.length !== bArray.length) {
      return false;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
      if (!deepEquals(aArray[i], bArray[i])) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  // Handle objects
  const keysA = Object.keys(a);
  const keysB = Object.keys(b);

  if (keysA.length !== keysB.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (const key of keysA) {
    if (!keysB.includes(key) || !deepEquals(a[key] as object, b[key] as object)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

I understand that when I declare a variable's type as `object`, it is interpreted as `{}`, which has no properties. But I don't know which type to declare instead.

> **any** type is refulsed by my linter config.

Comment: Found a solution by using: a[key as keyof typeof a] as object
Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b?rq=2 (R15's answer)