# How to use this key in angular 15

Tags: typescript, angular15

I am trying to set the value for the property using this. But it is not working in angular 15. I am getting error message like below:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'AppComponent'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type

How to resolve this issue?

app.compomnent.ts:

```
  export class AppComponent {
  aUser = false;
  bUser = false;
  cUser = false;

  arr = ['aUser', 'bUser', 'cUser'];

  value: string;
  changed(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.arr.forEach((val) => {
      if (val === value) {
        this[val] = true; // getting error
      } else {
        this[val] = false; // getting error
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-change-event-cxhzgy?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086672/element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-string-cant-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your component and html next way:

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  users = {
    aUser : false,
    bUser : false,
    cUser : false
  };

  arr = ['aUser', 'bUser', 'cUser'];

  value: string;
  changed(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.arr.forEach((val) => {
      if (val === value) {
        this.users[val] = true;
      } else {
        this.users[val] = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select #sel (change)="changed(sel.value)">
  <option value="aUser">A</option>
  <option value="bUser">B</option>
</select>
<pre>Value: {{value}}</pre>


<div *ngIf="users.aUser"> A </div>
<div *ngIf="users.bUser"> B </div>
<div *ngIf="users.cUser"> C </div>
```

You need to incapsulate accessable objects if you want to call them via string property name.

Updated option for Angular 15+:

**Component**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [CommonModule],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <select #sel (change)="changed(sel.value)">
  <option value="{{arr[0]}}">A</option>
  <option value="{{arr[1]}}">B</option>
  <option value="{{arr[2]}}">C</option>
</select>
<pre>Value: {{value}}</pre>

<div *ngIf="users[arr[0]]"> A </div>
<div *ngIf="users[arr[1]]"> B </div>
<div *ngIf="users[arr[2]]"> C </div>

<div *ngFor="let item of users | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  users: {[key: string]: boolean} = {
    aUser : false,
    bUser : false,
    cUser : false    
  };

  arr = ['aUser', 'bUser', 'cUser'];

  value: string = '';

  changed(value: string) {
    this.value = value;
    this.arr.forEach((val) => {
      
      this.arr.forEach((val) => {
        if (val === value) {
          this.users[val] = true; 
        } else {
          this.users[val] = false;
        }
      });
      
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Application:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nyrvpj?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Not working in angular 15

Comment: Any other way is there?

Comment: @sarann Updated the answer with option for Angular 15+