# typescript sort is wrong

Tags: typescript, sorting

I have array:

```
let a = [{id: "-1", name: "a"}, { id: "0", name: "b" }, { id: "1", name: "c" }]
```

I do the following:

```
a = a.sort(x => <number>x.id);
```

But for some reasons I have item with `id = "0"` in the last position. What's the reason of it and how can I fix it?

Also I tried to change `id = "0"` -> `id = "-2"` in array but now if I sort again I see the following order: `-1, -2, 1`. What's wrong?

Maybe there is an error in casting one type to another? I mean `string` to `number`

Comment: The sort callback is supposed to have the signature `function(a, b): int`. If you're trying to sort the items numerically by the `id` field, try something like `a.sort((a, b) => Number(a.id) - Number(b.id))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript sorting an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687907/typescript-sorting-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is not a runtime language, it compiles to JS. Doing a TS cast will only instruct the TS compiler to treat x.id a a `number` it will not perform a runtime cast.

What you want is to do a JS cast to number, e.g. `Number(x.id)`

Also, to properly sort you'll need to compare two items:

```
a.sort((x, y) => Number(x.id) - Number(y.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
a.sort((a, b) => { if (a.id < b.id) return -1; else if (a.id > b.id) return 1; else return 0; });
```