# Ascending or descending order of array of object in angular 10?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
this.tripDetails= [
              {
                "vehicleNumber": "TN 47 GR 3679",
                "adminVehicleDTO": [
                  {
                    "tripId": 107,
                    "id": 1176,
                    "vehicleNumber": "TN 47 GR 3679",
                    "nominalType": "income",
                    "typeOfService": "REGULAR",
                    "amount": 250.0,
                    "vehicleId": 1,
                    "adhocVehicleId": null,
                    "reason": "Trip Income",
                    "reasonId": 71,
                    "description": null,
                    "remarks": null,
                    "deleteFlag": false
                }]
            },
              {
                "vehicleNumber": "KL 34 CV 6296",
                "adminVehicleDTO": [
                   {
                    "tripId": 104,
                    "id": 1165,
                    "vehicleNumber": "KL 34 CV 6296",
                    "nominalType": "income",
                    "typeOfService": "REGULAR",
                    "amount": 0.0,
                    "vehicleId": null,
                    "adhocVehicleId": 32,
                    "reason": "Trip Income",
                    "reasonId": 71,
                    "description": null,
                    "remarks": null,
                    "deleteFlag": false
                }]
            }, 
              {
                "vehicleNumber": "AP 06 DE 4089",
                "adminVehicleDTO": [
                  {
                    "tripId": 106,
                    "id": 1175,
                    "vehicleNumber": "AP 06 DE 4089",
                    "nominalType": "income",
                    "typeOfService": "REGULAR",
                    "amount": 0.0,
                    "vehicleId": 4,
                    "adhocVehicleId": null,
                    "reason": "Trip Income",
                    "reasonId": 71,
                    "description": null,
                    "remarks": null,
                    "deleteFlag": false
                }]
            }]
```

This is the response from API and I want to make it either in ascending or descending order based on **vehicleNumber** in angular typescript for a purpose. I tried many things but nothing helped me. if possible suggest some ideas to try this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    private sortArrayOfObjectByPropertyName(items: any[], propertyName: string, isDescendingOrder: boolean = false) {
    items.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a[propertyName] < b[propertyName]) {
            return isDescendingOrder ? 1 : -1;
        }
        if (a[propertyName] > b[propertyName]) {
            return isDescendingOrder ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
tripDetails.sort(
 (n1,n2)=>{
    if (n1.vehicleNumber>n2.vehicleNumber) return 1;
    if (n1.vehicleNumber<n2.vehicleNumber) return -1;
    else return 0; 
})
```

should do the trick.

For sorting any type of array, the array.sort method takes a function argument, that can be called to compare any two members of the array. If the first arg (n1) is greater, return a positive number, if both are equal return 0 otherwise return a negative number. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21689268/2940917 for similar details.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily sort JavaScript arrays with `Array.prototype.sort()`, which you can read more about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Using a custom *compare function*, you can easily sort by an object's property.

You need an alphanumerical sort function, which you can easily find online. This function takes two parameters. These parameters are of the same type as the content of your array, in your case the object of a vehicle. You now have to pass the **vehicleNumber** of the parameter into the sort function, instead of the vehicle itself. Here is an extract from the Mozilla documentation, which fits your need pretty well:

> Objects can be sorted, given the value of one of their properties.

```
var items = [
  { name: 'Edward', value: 21 },
  { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 },
  { name: 'And', value: 45 },
  { name: 'The', value: -12 },
  { name: 'Magnetic', value: 13 },
  { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }
];

// sort by value
items.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.value - b.value;
});

// sort by name
items.sort(function(a, b) {
  var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is working fine also. Thanks guys.

```
this.regularIncomeDetails.sort((a, b) => a.vehicleNumber.localeCompare(b.vehicleNumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the JavaScript sort function.

1. Your parameter is `vehicleNumber`

```
{
                "vehicleNumber": "TN 47 GR 3679",
                "adminVehicleDTO": [
                  {
                    "tripId": 107,
                    "id": 1176,
                    "vehicleNumber": "TN 47 GR 3679",
                    "nominalType": "income",
                    "typeOfService": "REGULAR",
                    "amount": 250.0,
                    "vehicleId": 1,
                    "adhocVehicleId": null,
                    "reason": "Trip Income",
                    "reasonId": 71,
                    "description": null,
                    "remarks": null,
                    "deleteFlag": false
                }]
            },
```

2. Use the JS Sort fn with callback Fn

```
this.tripDetails.sort(function(a, b){
  var x = a.vehicleNumber.toLowerCase();
  var y = b.vehicleNumber.toLowerCase();
  if (x < y) {return -1;}
  if (x > y) {return 1;}
  return 0;
});
```